# How do you configure Spring-Security-LDAP plugin in Grails to use TLS?

Tags: java, grails, ldap, spring-security

Changing the authentication strategy to org.springframework.ldap.core.support.DefaultTlsDirContextAuthenticationStrategy may be the solution. But how/where do you configure that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this thread: http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Using-GORM-to-load-a-lot-of-data-and-to-keep-memory-usage-under-control-td3161909.html

Unfortunately there are two threads there since the AD question was asked as a reply and email subject change, so skip the first few messages.